# Call JRuby from MRI?

Tags: ruby, jruby, win32ole

I have a script that uses Win32OLE gem interact with a Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet but also needs to connect to Java database connection (JDBC).

The JRuby Win32OLE gem has several open issues (https://github.com/enebo/jruby-win32ole/issues) that doesn't allow me connect to Excel spreadsheet so I am wondering is it possible to write my Excel interaction with plain Ruby (MRI) and just call JRuby when I need to do my database interaction?

Comment: You could make a split application but that sounds pretty ugly. Why not just use MRI if you're constrained?

Comment: Database drivers are written in Java